# Proofs Involving Sets: Show that if P ⊆ Q, R ∩ P = P then R = Q. (Q is a set and R ⊆ Q)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to prove that R ∩ P = P for all P ⊆ Q, then R = Q. Q is a set and R ⊆ Q.

i.e. ∀ P ⊆ Q, R ∩ P = P then R = Q. (Q is a set and R ⊆ Q)

This is what I have got so far:

let z ∈ R ∩ P

z ∈ R and z ∈ P

P ⊆ R

since P ⊆ Q, z ∈ Q

...

but I'm not sure how to continue on from here.

Essentially to show R = Q, I am looking to show that Q ⊆ R because i already have R ⊆ Q.

Would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: hint: $R\subseteq Q$ means that $R= R\cap Q$… comment: what is $P$ in your proof? you haven’t instantiated what it is.

Comment: As stated, this cannot be proven. Counterexample: $P = \{ \}$, $R=\{1\}$, $Q=\{1,2\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to show that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equivalent is by showing that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.

You are given that $R \subseteq Q$ and you want to show that $R = Q$.

Therefore, the problem reduces to showing that $Q \subseteq R$.

The standard way of doing this is by taking any element $e$ in $Q$, and showing that this element must be in $R$.

By the premise of the problem, since  $\{e\} \subseteq Q, \{e\} \subseteq R.$

**Note**
As indicated in a comment following the question, $P \cap R = P$ is equivalent to $P \subseteq R$.

So, it is established that $Q \subseteq R$ and that therefore, $Q = R$.

**Edit**
I intentionally deferred a more elegant approach to emphasize that the basic definitions are often all that are needed.

The more elegant approach is to recognize that $Q \subseteq Q$ and that therefore, by the constraint of the problem, $Q \subseteq R$.